# Get physical path of virtual directory from desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-8

I have a virtual directory created in IIS named `VirtualDir`. It points to the UNC path `\\fileserver\folder1\folder2\`

I have a desktop application (`HttpContext.Current` is not available); and I'd like to retrieve the UNC path from the virtual directory name.

I know that if I was in a web context I could call `ServerApplication.MapPath("/VirtualDir/")`. I've tested in a web application and this works, but it doesn't help me.

I've tried `HostingEnvironment.MaptPath("/VirtualDir/")` but that returns null.

How can I retrieve the physical location of an IIS virtual directory from a desktop application, given the name of the virtual directory (and assuming it is under the default website).

Comment: If it's a desktop application then it's totally separate from IIS, why do you need the path from IIS and can you not supply it as part of some web call?

Comment: @Lloyd All I'm given is the name of the VDir - the physical path changes between environments, so I'd like to figure it out on the fly if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ServerManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager(v=vs.90).aspx) (needs admin privileges) from [Microsoft.Web.Administration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration(v=vs.90).aspx). For example

```
var server = new ServerManager();
var path = server.Sites["Site Name"]
    .Applications["Application Name"]
    .VirtualDirectories["Directory"]
    .PhysicalPath;
```